# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2070 to array axis with dimension 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, append, series

### Trying to perform k means clustering by appending multiple csv files with time series data.
But getting below error
104
{2070}

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
71 km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=cluster_count, metric="dtw")
72
---> 73 labels = km.fit_predict(mySeries)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tslearn\clustering\kmeans.py in fit_predict(self, X, y)
810             Index of the cluster each sample belongs to.
811         """
--> 812         X = check_array(X, allow_nd=True, force_all_finite='allow-nan')
813         return self.fit(X, y).labels_
814

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
529                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
530                 else:
--> 531                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
532             except ComplexWarning:
533                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
83
84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
86
87

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2070 to array axis with dimension 2

My code is:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(directory+filename)
mySeries.append(df)
        namesofMySeries.append(filename[:-2])
print(len(mySeries))
series_lengths = {len(series) for series in mySeries}
print(series_lengths)
cluster_count = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(mySeries))) 

km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=cluster_count, metric="dtw")

labels = km.fit_predict(mySeries)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have multi dimension arrays, by looking at the error message, could you do a print of the data frame head and the shape of the data frame? Also the variable mySeries is a list of dataframes? Cause that might be the issue, you probably need to concat that list before, if all the csvs files share the same schema structure, you could easily just do something like this:
\

```
final_df = pd.concat(mySeries)
```

Comment: Printing the shape and series gives 104
{2070}
Hour    object
Flow     int64
dtype: object
[                  Hour  Flow
0     01-12-2020 20:00   400
1     01-12-2020 21:00   199
2     01-12-2020 22:00    92
3     01-12-2020 23:00     4
4     02-12-2020 00:00     2
...                ...   ...
2065  28-02-2021 17:00  1549
2066  28-02-2021 18:00  1586
2067  28-02-2021 19:00  1471

[2070 rows x 2 columns],                   Hour  Flow                                                      pd.concat() gives shape (215280,). but it should be {2070, 2070}

Comment: @GaganbirKaur I think the problem might be how the data frames are being saved into the list. if you make sure that the first dataframe has the structure you want and that all the files save the same schema, you can be sure pd.concat() will just stack those dataframes into one